# Not all path return a value in switch

Tags: c#

I still get the error even if i already have a `default` clause

```
bool Validate(TextBox textBox , string type)
           // textboxL - textbox accept only letters of alphabets and space.Is Mandatory
           // textboxS - textbox accept  letters of alphabets , space , - , _  .Is Mandatory
          // return true by default
        {
            switch(type)
            {
                case "textboxL":
                    if (!Regex.IsMatch(textBox.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$") || String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text)) {
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid!!" + textBox.Text + "must  contain only letters and shouldn't be empty");
                        return false;
                    }  
                    break;
                case "textboxS":
                    if (!Regex.IsMatch(textBox.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z-_ ]+$") || String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text)) { 
                        return false; 
                    }
                    break;
                default: return true; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your return statements in the cases are inside of `if` blocks so you have paths that do not end up in a return statement.

Comment: Since you're already using if conditionals inside your switch cases, why not simply creating a complete if-structure ? That way, you would have been able to find your bug fairly quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` clauses in the switch are missing `else`

```
switch(type) {
    case "A" : if (condition) return true; else return false; break;
    case "b" : if (condition) return true; else return false; break;
...
...
}
```

This way, if the condition in any of the cases aren't met, you also return a value.

Answer (score 3):

If `type=="textboxL"` and the inner condition turns out to be false, your function won't return any value. Same with `"textboxS"`.

Notice that `default` is called only if we didn't go inside the other `case`s (in this case where you use `break` at the end of each `case`).

Depending on your logic, you may want to `return true` at the end of the function.

Comment: You should add to your answer not only that but also code. So that instead of writing the default, he should return true if condition wasn't met in the case.